# What definition of change in potential energy applies to a multi-particle system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

I read a text:

> We define change in potential energy of the system corresponding to conservative internal forces as:-.
>   $$\Delta U = -W = -\int \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$$ 
>   as the system goes from one configuration to another.

I can't understand what $d\mathbf{r}$ represents when we talk about a multi-particle system.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future to format any equations in your question: to help this time, I've edited your question, and also made some minor changes to the title and wording. You can check the formatting if you click on the "edit" link just below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that equation for each particle in the system separately. Then you can add up everything at the end. In other words:

$$\Delta U_{system}=\sum_i(\Delta U)_i=-\sum_i\int\mathbf F_i\cdot\text d\mathbf r_i$$

Where the sum over $i$ covers all particles of the system.